# opening a new tab from an existing tab without keeping the current $sessionStorage data in the new tab

Tags: angularjs, sessionstorage

i use `$window.open()` to open the same tab. the problem is that `$sessionStorage` object is the same in the new tab as in the original tab. i understand that it's because of top-level browsing (read about it in thes question [How to prevent sessionStorage being inherited when using target="_blank"/window.open() to open a new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20879714/how-to-prevent-sessionstorage-being-inherited-when-using-target-blank-window) and in here https://www.webdirections.org/blog/webstorage-persistent-client-side-data-storage/). what i am looking for is a way to open a new tab from inside the old tab with a new empty `$sessionStorage` (only for the new tab).

old tab

```
$sessionStorage.text = "aaaaaaa";
$window.open("http://sameTab/different/state");
```

new tab

```
$sessionStorage.text = "aaaaaaa";
```

Comment: Im not sure this is possible, but whats the use case?

Comment: i'm trying to open the login state in a new tab but  because my sessionStorage is not empty the user is already past login

Comment: id say you need a different way of validating the user, other than session...